# UISwitch sticking in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am updating some Core Data entries using a UISWitch embedded inside a UITableViewCell.

When the switch is toggled I need it to refresh the table, though at the minute the UISwitch just stays where it.

I suspect it is something to do with the model I am using? Below is the code from the UITableVIewCell, where I update the Core Data entry, and then using the tableview reference, I attempt to reload data on the table. The UI doesnt reload though unless I exit the view and return, so I know the Core Data entity is being updated correctly.

I suspect it's because my surveyQuestionReference is always set to the same value?

```
class SurveyQuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBOutlet weak var lblQuestion: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var toggQuestion: UISwitch!
var surveyQuestionReference : SurveyQuestion?
var tableViewReference : UITableView?

@IBAction func toggledQuestion(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tempContext: NSManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    tempContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext

    tempContext.performBlock({
        let entityName = "CoreDataObject"
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workId = %@", self.surveyQuestionReference!.workId)
        do {

            let results = try tempContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [NSManagedObject]

            if results!.count > 0{

                    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext{
                        moc.performBlockAndWait({


                            [unowned self] in
                            for result in results!{
                               result.setValue(self.toggQuestion.on, forKey: (self.surveyQuestionReference?.property)!)
                            }

                        })





                }
            }
            do {
                try tempContext.save()

            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }

    })
    print(sender)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        // load data

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // update ui

            self.tableViewReference!.reloadData()
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting the models property before reloading the table:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        // load data

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // update ui
            self.surveyQuestionReference?.answer = self.toggQuestion.on
            self.tableViewReference!.reloadData()
        }
    }
```